# rviz camera display locked in top left corner of screen

Tags: ros, rviz, ubuntu, ubuntu-lucid, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I add a camera plugin in rviz it appears at the top left of the screen. It is stuck under the application bar and I cannot move it.

When I switch compiz off, I can move it and dock it to rviz and switching compiz back on is OK, so I can then still move it around.

Does anyone know the reason for this or how to fix it?

I am using Ubuntu Lucid with gnome and compiz. The graphics card is a nVidia GT240.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9642/rviz-camera-display-locked-in-top-left-corner-of-screen/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2011-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue will be fixed in the next rviz release by creating new windows at (30,30)

---

Originally posted by [David Gossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/497/david-gossow/) with karma: 26 on 2011-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also have this issue occasionally. I worked around it by activating the hide buttons on the Ubuntu main panel, so I can hide the panel, grab the camera window and then unhide the panel again. But I´d also be interested in a real solution.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

either the tip from stefan, or -with focus on the camera window- use alt-space to popup the window menu and select "move"

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1